Websocket with Python error: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired
EDIT: I am providing the official code for the websocket asyncio server example from python websocket webpage: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
The [WinError 121] appears when a client connects with the server and then disconnects abnormally by losing network connectivity. To test this, I intentionally tried to connect a client with the WebSocket server, and then, while the connection was open, I turned off the client's network. Then, the error appeared.
Here is how you can reproduce the error:

Copy the server code and paste it into a py file and run it
Get any client method. I used Postman from another PC (not the same host running the server). You can also use WebSocket client apps on your smartphone.
Make sure to have both, the computer running the server and the client on the same network.
Identify the server IP Address
Connect the client to the server
Turn Off the network of the client while keeping the connection open. (By means of turning off WiFi, unplugging the Ethernet cable etc.)
Wait for about 30 seconds, you will see the mentioned error appear.

Please find the server code below:
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Echo server using the asyncio API."""

import asyncio
from websockets.asyncio.server import serve


async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)


async def main():
    async with serve(echo, "0.0.0.0", 8765) as server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Note that I tried the same thing with the threading example provided on the python websocket page and did not get any error, or message at all.
I think it has to do something with asyncio.
To have a better understanding of the error, I am providing the full uncut stack trace.
Please find the log of the app below:
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", 
line 286, in _loop_reading
    length = fut.result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 803, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 462, in finish_socket_func
    return ov.getresult()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\websockets\asyncio\server.py", line 374, in conn_handler
    await self.handler(connection)
  File "e:\Programming\asyncio websocket\server.py", line 10, in echo
    async for message in websocket:
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\websockets\asyncio\connection.py", line 224, in __aiter__
    yield await self.recv()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jusuf Rrustaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\websockets\asyncio\connection.py", line 279, in recv
    raise self.protocol.close_exc from self.recv_exc
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent

What is the solution I am looking for?
To have a piece of code that identifies that the client has lost the connection and to not throw errors.

Did you intentionally cut out the stack trace?

Yes, I did that on purpose. I can provide it if needed. But please run the code and see for yourself. This error is frustrating me.

How do expect us to reproduce the problem without your environment, without the client code and without the traceback?

I see that your log contains the print statement "Client ... connection closed".  As far as I can see, the only place in your code where such a statement occurs is in the block except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed.  To get into that block, you must in fact be catching that exception already.  Perhaps it's a subclass of OSError.  Am I missing something?
